# Have . / source to work performing total replacement of current loaded/sourced one

Tags: bash

How to have `.` / `source` work to perform total replacement of current
loaded/run sourced codes script as e.g.

$ . bashscript

just add commands/codes script to the  current loaded/run sourced one,
while may replace if only it is coincidentally the same identifier
name

But so explain how to have its total replacement as if it cleans up the
current loaded/run source before sourcing the new

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to revert arbitrary commands. Compare this answer of mine: [*why `source` not refresh the `.bashrc` file*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698166/108618).

What you can do is to start a *fresh* shell and then source exactly what you want. Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Useful [options for Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html): `--noprofile`, `--norc` or `--rcfile filename`.

Other tricks:

- `exec program` replaces the current shell with `program`, the PID will stay.
- `env -i program` runs `program` in an empty environment.

The following command will thus replace your current shell with a quite clean `bash`:

```
cd / && exec env -i bash --noprofile --norc
```

The command is probably not very useful alone, but may be a good starting point.

Notes:

- This does not touch file descriptors. Append `</dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty` to the command, to connect stdin, stdout and stderr (file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 respectively) to the controlling terminal for sure (in case they have been redirected to elsewhere), if this is what you want. Closing other single-digit file descriptors (that may have been opened) can be performed with the following loop:

  ```bash
  for i in {3..9}; do
     exec {i}>&-
  done
  unset i
  ```

  ([Higher numbers should not be used anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475409/108618).) You can automatically run this loop by placing it in a file and using `--rcfile …` instead of `--norc`.
- Empty environment means no `$TERM`, so you may prefer

  ```
  env -i TERM="$TERM" bash …
  ```

  There are other environment variables you may want to keep: `$SHELL`, `$PAGER`, `$HOME`, `$USER`, `$PATH`, … See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49057/108618). In theory each of them may have been altered by something you sourced, so relying on their current values is not necessarily the best idea. You can specify your desired values explicitly.
- Our interactive `bash` will still use the default history file and related settings, so history expansion may work and depend on what you did earlier. See how to [start bash session without history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384997/108618).